# MongoParseError: Load balancer mode requires driver version 4+

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I have built a loopback 3 app with mongodb, worked perfectly on local and vps. But I wanted to opt for the SaaS (mongodb.com and heroku.com) and now I am facing an error:

```
    /node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:698
          throw error;
          ^

MongoParseError: Load balancer mode requires driver version 4+
```

I have updated the loopback-connector-mongodb, installed mongodb 4.4.0 through npm and made sure of the compatibility.

P.S: since I am using the shared plan from mongodb.com, I cannot turn off the load balancer.

Answer (score 3):

if u want to use serverless mongo. mongoose version should be higher than 6. To fix the above issue update the mongoose

npm install mongoose@6.5.3

Comment: Here is a link from the MongoDB forums regarding the same topic - https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-serverless-instance-connection-with-mongoose-js/224493/3. Also, it mentions the compatibility table of Serverless - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/serverless-instance-limitations/#minimum-driver-versions-for-serverless-instances.